# How to attach a "lean to" shed to a garage?

Tags: garage, construction, shed

I recently purchased the [plans for this](https://www.howtobuildashed.org/download/FREE_6x10_Shed_Plan.pdf) 10'x6' Lean To Shed.  It is designed to be free-standing, but I'd like to attach this to the back of my garage, which is more than large enough to accommodate.  This shed will be a bike shed and I plan to hang some bikes off the inside back wall.

My question: What is the best way to attach it? I figure I have three primary options:

1. Attach it at the roof line, and leave a couple of inches of space between the back wall of the shed and the garage
2. Attach the back wall to the shed and adjust the roof to eliminate the overhang
3. Eliminate the back wall completely, attach the side walls to the garage, and adjust the roof to eliminate the overhang

What is the best approach?  Is there a different approach that I'm missing?  Are there other considerations I should think about?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide some drawings of your intent? How large is the garage? What are the relative orientations of the garage and shed? Do you know if your jurisdiction considers this an addition to an existing structure and requires permitting? Would you be willing to modify the existing garage to add the space you desire?

Comment: Without outlining your criteria, this question is entirely subjective. If you outline your criteria the answer will probably become apparent.

Comment: And for what it's worth I would end the roof flush with the back wall and position the shed against your garage without attaching it at all. I see absolutely no benefit to attaching it, which would only serve to damage the siding on the garage. Why not leave the shed unattached and therefore potentially mobile?

Comment: @isherwood If you don’t attach the shed to the garage, the shed could move slightly during wind storms, moving heavy items in and out, etc., which could scratch up the two wall finishes.

Comment: @isherwood Securing the two structures together allows you to seal the space between the two buildings from wind blown rain, dryrot, mold, etc.

Comment: @isherwood What do you mean by "outlining my criteria"?  My criteria (as I understand the term): I want a place to keep all the family bikes and I want it to look like it is part of the garage when sitting outside.  But I'm guessing from your question that I'm not understanding it properly.  Can you give me an example of the criteria you would need to make this less subjective?

Comment: @BrianGenisio Criteria for defining the "best way" (while still remaining on-topic here). Most structurally sound, simplest, least amount of demo, seamless looks (as you mentioned), those kinds of things.

Comment: @isherwood I care about it being structurally sound enough to hang some bikes on the back wall, whether it be the wall of the shed, or the wall of the garage (if I remove the rear shed wall).  I expect I'll have to remove the cedar shake shingles with options 2 and 3 and I'm ok with that.  Other than that, I don't expect much more demo.

Answer (score 3):

I see no reason to use Option 1.  My daughter would just find a way to loose her hula hoop (and everything else she owns) in that little space between the garage and shed.

I like Option 2. Attaching the wall AND roof directly to something solid will keep the shed rigid. Also, having the back wall installed will allow you to fasten machinery and equipment to the wall without affecting the existing garage wall.

Option 3 would give you a few more inches of floor space, but you’d have to “hang” everything directly on the garage wall. Also, if you ever decide to insulate the shed, you’d have trouble insulating the common wall.